# Infinity Blade III Worker of Secrets Level?

Tags: infinity-blade-3

Okay, so.
I was playing IB3, I wanted to check my status on GC and I found this: http://m1310.hizliresim.com/1g/9/tdyxz.jpg
"Worker of Secrets Level"
What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Have you played the Worker of Secrets boss fight?  I am assuming that leaderboard is referring to that specific fight.

Below is the actual fight with the Worker of Secrets:

*The Worker of Secrets also known as Galath is a Deathless who created the Infinity Blade. A long time ago, he was imprisoned in the Vault of Tears by Ausar before he was freed by Siris. He possesses a great understanding of the Q.I.P. and the Deathless. He is also one of the greatest swordsmen in his time, easily defeating Radriar.*

Comment: Yeah, I did. ;-;

Comment: Either that, or it is about a section you havent reached yet in the game or hasn't been released yet.